# Incomplete selection in OneNote

Tags: microsoft-onenote, selection

When I select text in OneNote, it happens quite often that it looks like a part of the text hasn't been selected, like in this screen shot:

[image: Selection example, selecting from bottom to top]

As you notice, the text `If you select t` has no grey background and looks like it isn't selected. This happens several times a day. In fact it is selected and switching to another application and back to OneNote causes a repaint and reveal the full selection.

[image: Selection example, selecting from top to bottom]

When selecting from top to bottom, it seems that the selection issue is more often at the end of the line. When selecting from bottom to top, is seems missing at the beginning of the line.

This behavior is distracting and I find myself reselecting text more often than necessary.

Is there a known fix for this kind of bug? I'm using OneNote 2016.0.14131.20278 x64. I'm using the mouse to select the text.

I have tried:

- turning off hardware acceleration in OneNote options
- doing an Office Online Repair (+ Reboot) as suggested by [JW0914](https://superuser.com/users/529800/jw0914)

Comment: Perform an online repair of Office via `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features` _(or if it's the UWP app, uninstall/reinstall via the Windows Store)_. If that doesn't fix it, the issue isn't with OneNote.

Comment: @JW0914 unfortunately the online repair didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not know the solution, and I found that this error happens only in the desktop version (not UWP).

I am also having the same problem in my OneNote since a couple of months, and I am pretty sure my system was not corrupted. It mostly occurs when I select the text a bit faster.

Here are my specs for a reference:

- Microsoft® OneNote® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version `2111 Build 16.0.14701.20206`) 64-bit
- Windows `10 Pro 21H2`

Indeed, it is pretty annoying, and I am quite surprised that it is unpopular on the web. I have already reported it to the Microsoft team through the `File` > `Feedback` menu, and I hope that the fix will come in the next releases.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).